# How to delete data from a table in mysql Using a subquery

Tags: mysql

I have this query with returned rows a alias and in keyword in mysql.I would like to delete all returned row that value is less or equal to 0 in the same table.

```
 delete from tblmusterproject where final in(
 SELECT final from (select sum(Crowd+Review+Lp+additions+deductions+monthly) as final,
 employeeno FROM tblmusterproject
 group by employeeno) as b) <=0;
```

am get this Error "Unknown column 'final' in 'IN/ALL/ANY subquery'"
How can i do it.

Comment: Incidentally, I'm not convinced that your schema design is optimal

Comment: @Strawberry unfortunately that didn't answer my question nor did it assist me in the question i needed help on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have <=0 that seems in wrong position   and yout

If you want delete the employeeno when filter value (alias  the sum) <= 0 then you could use having  in subquery for get the employeeid you need

and instead of a in clause you could use a join

```
 delete t
 from tblmusterproject t
 INNER JOIN  ( 
    Select sum(Crowd+Review+Lp+additions+deductions+monthly) as final, employeeno 
    FROM tblmusterproject
    group by employeeno
    HAVING final = <=0
)  b on b.employeeno = t.employeeno
```